# PHP create 1 array of 4 arrays ordered by index

Tags: php, arrays

I have 4 arrays, each one holds another column of a table, I would like to create one array with the data ordered per array[$i]. All arrays have the same number of values: $namesArr, $folderArr, $updatedAt, $valuesArr .
I would like my new array to be contain:

```
$namesArr[0], $folderArr[0], $updatedAt[0], $valuesArr[0],
$namesArr[1], $folderArr[1], $updatedAt[1], $valuesArr[1],
$namesArr[2], $folderArr[2], $updatedAt[2], $valuesArr[2],
...
```

I guess the solution is pretty simple, but I got stuck :(
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you add sample array with values?

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, $newArray =array( $namesArr,  $folderArr, $updatedAt, $valuesArr), now $newArray will have all the columns. to fetch $namesArr[0]. you would do $newArray[0][0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
$arr = array_map(function () { return func_get_args(); },$namesArr, $folderArr, $updatedAt, $valuesArr);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach loop to merge 4 arrays:

```
foreach ($namesArr as $key => $value) {
    $arr[$key][] = $value;
    $arr[$key][] = $folderArr[$key];
    $arr[$key][] = $updatedAt[$key];
    $arr[$key][] = $valuesArr[$key];
}
```

Thus $arr will be the merged array

Answer (score 0):

do the following way:

```
while($db->query($sql)){
$namesArr[] =$db->f('names');
$folderArr[]=$db->f('folder');
$updatedAt[]=$db->f('updated');
$valuesArr[]=$db->f('values');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$newArr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($namesArr); $i++)
{
    $newArr[$i][0] = $namesArr[$i];
    $newArr[$i][1] = $folderArr[$i];
    $newArr[$i][2] = $updatedAt[$i];
    $newArr[$i][3] = $valuesArr[$i];
}
?>
```

#### Explanation

What this will do is iterate depending on how many elements there are in `$namesArr`.

I utilised a [multidimensional array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp) here so that the first set of square brackets is effectively the "row" in a table, and the second set of square brackets are the "column" of a table.